# I am facing woo commerce single product image gallery thumbnails CSS Styling problem - Using Elementor and Hello

Tags: elementor

I have import a template kit with Elementor Pro. Applied all the templets on website such as Homepage, header and footer etc.
I applied the template on single product in EP Editor it looks fine but on website preview, the single product image thumbnails gallery is vertical, It's like broken CSS Styling or a conflict or plugins.
Tried many ways but didn't work.

I tried to deactivate the installed plugins one by one and clean the cache but did not work for me.